# Javascript Regex Matching Everything

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this bit of Javascript,

```
if (/[A-Za-z0-9-]+/.test(sZip)) {
   alert(Match!);
}
```

and I'm using this as my test case "1234;"

I don't want "1234;" to be a match, I want only for example "1234" or "12 34" or "12-34" to match.

Comment: `Match!` should be contained within quotes.

Comment: Just a short clarification: Should ';1234' be a match?

Comment: @exiva, if you want to match everything, then `"12 34"` should _not_ be matched since it contains a space. Or did you forget to include it in your character class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/[A-Za-z0-9-]+$/
```

(The $ is the key: it means end of string, no more characters)

Comment: Sorry, I previously made a comment recommending to add the `^`, but it looks like this should probably not be done (see my comment beneath Boldewyn's answer).

Comment: Hmm true that, removed again :)

Answer (score 3):

Start the regular expression with `^` and end it with `$`. This way you tell it to match the whole string against the pattern. [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

If you want the space matched, you need to include it in the brackets. For space and dash to delimit alphanum fields, take this approach:

```
/^([A-Za-z0-9]+[ -])*[A-Za-z0-9]+$/
---^ 0 or more "ABC123-" fields
---------------^ separated by either dash or space
---------------------^ but at least once a "ABC123" field (no dash)
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't think the OP wants the `^` since he want `"12 34"` to be matched, which contains a space that is not contained in his char-set `[A-Za-z0-9-]`.

Comment: Let's ask him. I got the need for `^` from the question title.

Answer (score 2):

```
    if (/[A-Za-z0-9-]+$/.test(sZip)) { 
      alert(Match!); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
if (/[A-Za-z0-9-]+\s/.test(sZip)) {
   alert(Match!);
}
```